# How to transfer C drive with Windows 8 OS to a new hard drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8, ssd

I have an OCZ Agility 3 SSD capacity 64GB, i bought a new SSD Vertex 4 capacity 128GB, how can i move all my C: drive contents including files \  windows 8 \ mbr \ boot basically everything to the new SSD \ Hard drive without reinstalling windows 8, and copying all my settings and files?

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think it is possible to copy **everything**

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily (and very fast) done with [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/).
I suggest cloning the entire disk, than resizing the partition to fill the ssd (or make another partition there, whatever you want)

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of solutions.

Acronis has been the go-to for years for many people. There is also Easus (they have a free version http://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/), CloneZilla (as mentioned) and more.

Acronis and Easus are both great, and I have heard good things about Clonezilla too, although I never used it.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Acronis True Image, it's easy and fast. (true image is not free)

However, there's a lot of software doing exactly what you need:

- ghost (ex norton ghost)
- easis drive cloning
- easus disk copy
- ping
- clonezilla

I always suggest you to do the cloning process using a live cd (all of those software have a live cd).

for reference, just take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_cloning_software